# How to send a FIX message with custom tag ordering?

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

The order request is sent on FIX server and the order of tags is changed.

What if I wanted output for the sequence as it is arranged by me (and not getting modified by the server).

```
public void send50(Order order) {

    quickfix.fix50sp1.NewOrderSingle newOrderSingle = new quickfix.fix50sp1.NewOrderSingle(new ClOrdID(order.getID()),
            sideToFIXSide(order.getSide()), new TransactTime(), typeToFIXType(order.getType()));
    newOrderSingle.set(new OrderQty(order.getQuantity()));
    newOrderSingle.set(new Symbol(order.getSymbol()));
    newOrderSingle.set(new Price(order.getSharePrice()));
    newOrderSingle.set(new Account("13501100"));
    newOrderSingle.setField(new NoPartyIDs(1));
    newOrderSingle.setField(new PartyIDSource('C'));
    newOrderSingle.setField(new PartyRole(12));
    newOrderSingle.setField(new PartyID("13501100"));**
```

This is the sequence given by the user to the server and it is arranged by the server as:

**8=FIXT.1.1|9=173|35=D|34=5|49=135|52=20200131-05:35:12.956|56=PSE|1=13501100|11=1580448912441|38=1000|40=1|44=10.78|54=1|55=AGI|59=0|60=20200131-13:35:12.956|447=C|448=13501100|452=12|453=1|10=213|**

So what can be done if I wanted the output in the same sequence which is sent?

Comment: If the tags aren't part of a repeating group, you should not care as the FIX protocol doesn't care about the order of tags that are not in a repeating group. Is this something you want just for the sake of wanting it? Does your counterparty have a non-conforming FIX implementation that requires a specific sequence outside repeating groups? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Actually, I want to send order request as per my given example but when I send the request on FIX server then it will be changed automatic. just like this:-

1=13501100|11=1580448912441|38=1000|40=1|44=10.78|54=1|55=AGI|59=0|60=20200131-13:35:12.956|447=C|448=13501100|452=12|453=1|10=213|

so I just want to ask that can I send the order single request like this:-

11=1580448912441|38=1000|40=1|44=10.78|54=1|55=AGI|59=0|60=20200131-13:35:12.956|1=13501100|453=1|447=C|452=12|448=13501100|10=213|

Comment: User TT is correct, and you need to read their comment again.  You didn't answer their questions.

Answer (score 8):

Grant and TT are correct in stating that actually FIX does not mandate a specific tag (or field) ordering except inside repeating groups.
However, there are some counterparties which require a specific field ordering in the message body.

When setting fields on a message, QuickFIX/J arranges the tags in the order as they appear in the data dictionary. This is because the code for a specific message type is generated from the data dictionary on compile time.

If you wanted to change this ordering there are two possibilities.

1. Change the data dictionary and recompile QuickFIX/J. Instructions are here: [build instructions](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj#build-instructions)
2. Extend the general `Message`, specify the tag ordering and pass it to the super constructor. See below for example code.
   **NOTE:** Thinking further about this I realized that there is a downside to this approach. In the case of the event that your side needs to resend messages, then the messages from the store are parsed using the configured data dictionary and message factory for that session. I.e. you will probably end up using the field ordering from the data dictionary / generated code again.
   So to sum this up: option 1 is the clean approach but requires rebuilding QuickFIX/J.

And a general note: please note that you don't have to add the repeating group count (`NoPartyIDs` in your code) by yourself. This is done by QuickFIX/J when you add a group to the message.

Example code:

```java
@Test
    public void testCustomFieldOrder() {

        final int[] FIELD_ORDER = {38, 55, 44, 1};
        final int[] PARTY_GROUP_ORDER = {447, 452, 448, 0};

        class MyNewOrderSingle extends quickfix.fix50sp1.Message {

            public static final String MSGTYPE = "D";

            public MyNewOrderSingle() {
                super(FIELD_ORDER);
                getHeader().setField(new quickfix.field.MsgType(MSGTYPE));
            }

        }

        class MyPartyGroup extends Group {

            public MyPartyGroup() {
                super(453, 447, PARTY_GROUP_ORDER);
            }

        }

        quickfix.fix50sp1.NewOrderSingle nos1 = new quickfix.fix50sp1.NewOrderSingle();
        nos1.setString(38, "1000");
        nos1.setString(55, "SYM");
        nos1.setString(44, "1");
        nos1.setString(1, "ACCOUNT");
        nos1.setString(100, "XETR");
        quickfix.fix50sp1.NewOrderSingle.NoPartyIDs group1 = new quickfix.fix50sp1.NewOrderSingle.NoPartyIDs();
        group1.setString(447, "C");
        group1.setString(452, "12");
        group1.setString(448, "PARTYID");
        nos1.addGroup(group1);

        System.out.println("orig   " + nos1.toString().replace('\001', '|'));

        MyNewOrderSingle nos2 = new MyNewOrderSingle();
        nos2.setString(38, "1000");
        nos2.setString(55, "SYM");
        nos2.setString(44, "1");
        nos2.setString(1, "ACCOUNT");
        nos2.setString(100, "XETR");

        MyPartyGroup group2 = new MyPartyGroup();
        group2.setString(447, "C");
        group2.setString(452, "12");
        group2.setString(448, "PARTYID");
        nos2.addGroup(group2);

        System.out.println("custom " + nos2.toString().replace('\001', '|'));

    }
```

Output:

```
orig   8=FIXT.1.1|9=75|35=D|1=ACCOUNT|38=1000|44=1|55=SYM|100=XETR|453=1|448=PARTYID|447=C|452=12|10=014|
custom 8=FIXT.1.1|9=75|35=D|38=1000|55=SYM|44=1|1=ACCOUNT|100=XETR|453=1|447=C|452=12|448=PARTYID|10=014|
```

Comment: When you write: "Change the data dictionary and recompile QuickFIX/J. Instructions are here: build instructions", Which quickfix project file do you mean exactly?
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74091489/how-to-build-quickfixj-from-a-custom-dictionary?noredirect=1#comment130824687_74091489 here is an example for the FIX44 dictionary.