# QuickFixN: How to set fields in a specific sequence on a QuoteRequest message?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

We have a requirement to send the first 3 fields of the message in the order that they are set, i.e. QuoteReqID, OnBehalfOfCompID, Account. However when they are added to the message, they get reordered numerically ascending, i.e. Account, OnBehalfOfCompID, QuoteReqID. With the group, we are able to define the field order but I see no option to do this for the message. Does anybody know how we can achieve this?

```
            var message = new QuoteRequest();
            int[] fieldOrder = new[] {Tags.Currency, Tags.Symbol, Tags.SecurityType, Tags.CFICode, Tags.NoLegs, Tags.LegQty, Tags.LegFutSettDate, Tags.LegSecuritySubType};

            message.SetField(new QuoteReqID(stream.QuoteRequestId));
            message.SetField(new OnBehalfOfCompID(_compId));
            message.SetField(new Account(_accountId));
            var group = new Group(Tags.NoRelatedSym, 0, fieldOrder);
            group.SetField(new Currency(stream.Ccy));
            group.SetField(new Symbol(stream.Ccy1 + "/" + stream.Ccy2));
            group.SetField(new SecurityType("FOR"));
            group.SetField(new CFICode("FORWARD"));
            group.SetField(new NoLegs(1));
            group.SetField(new LegQty(stream.Amount));
            group.SetField(new LegFutSettDate(stream.FutSettDate));
            group.SetField(new LegSecuritySubType("TOD"));

            message.AddGroup(group);

            QuickFix.Session.SendToTarget(message, _ratesSession.SessionId);
```

Comment: Not familiar with QF/n but in QF/J you'll have to call a specific `Message` or `FieldMap` constructor which you can pass the field order just like you did with the `group`. But as Grant and Ciaran pointed out your mileage may vary since it is really no standard thing that is going on there.

Comment: Christoph, are you saying that you can specify Body-level field order in QF/j?

Comment: Lewis, can you send me a private email (see grantb.net) and tell me who your counterparty is?  Really wondering who it is that's doing this.  It's not the first time I've seen this request.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier yes that is possible. Thought it was in QF/n too but maybe I am confusing it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60048848/4962355 However doing it in the code (without regenerating the message classes) has some drawbacks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely not how FIX protocol is specified to behave.  In the spec, fields in the Body that are not inside a repeating group can be in any order.  Your counterparty is asking for non-FIX-compliant behavior (and I can see no benefit for it).

As such, QuickFIX/n does not support this, because... QF/n implements FIX, and not this stupid non-FIX behavior that your counterparty wants.

I'm sorry to tell you this, but you will have to hack the engine somehow to make this happen.

**One more caveat:** `OnBehalfOfCompID` is a header field, not a body field.  QF/n should not have a problem with you adding it to an *outgoing* message's body, but it would likely reject such a message when incoming.  (Thanks to @ciaran-mchale 's answer for pointing this out.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will get correct the OnBehalfOfCompID field and retry. It is useful to know that it's not standard behaviour so I'm wondering if there's something else amiss and they've just referenced a sample working response and noticed the sequences didn't match and pointed that out first.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with QuickFixN, but I know that `OnBehalfOfCompID` is a field in the *header* of a message, while both `QuoteReqID` and `Account` are fields in the *body* of a message. All header fields used in a message *must* appear before any of the body fields.

Comment: Good catch.  I don't think QF/n would complain if you added it to a message body, though.  It would complain if it was in the body of a received message though.  (What does this counterparty think they're doing?)

Answer (score 0):

"onbehalfcompid" ( tag 115) comes under header of fix message and quoteReqID ( tag 131) and Account (tag 1) comes under body of fix message. and all header tags should appear before the body message tags. and this is applicable to all fix engines/simulator.