# quickfixj DataDictionary Validation Issue

Tags: quickfixj

I'm new to Java. Working on QuikcFixJ.

I'm trying to load custom.xml file using datadictionary and later parsing msg string from this datadictionary. Not sure what is wrong with datadictionary , its not throwing any error whether I pass correct fix.xml file path or incorrect one.
Later when I pass msg string to Message object it just parse initial 3 tags irrespective of whatever xml file I mention in datadictionary.

Please give me some pointers to resolve it.

---

### **Adding code snippet:**

```
public Message createMsg(String type, String message) 
{
        message = "35=" + type + "\001" + message;
        message = "8=FIX4.2\0019=" + message.length() + "\001"+message ;
        String msgCharStr = message.replaceAll("\\|", "\001");
        int checksum = MessageUtils.checksum(msgCharStr);
        msgCharStr = msgCharStr +"\00110=" +  (1 + 
        MessageUtils.checksum(msgCharStr)) + "\001" ;
        quickfix.Message msg = new Message();
        msg.fromString(msgCharStr, null,true);
}
```

This code works fine for regular neworder or quoterequest msgs.
But, when I pass quoterequest msg with custom repeating group which I loaded via UseDictionary config settings, it gives undesired output msg.
e.g: Lets say if I pass input, "35=R|146=1|...|453=2|448=XX|447=G|452=1|448=YY|447=D|452=2|......"

parser gives output as :
"35=R|146=1|...|448=XX|447=G|452=1|453=2|448=YY|447=D|452=2|......"

---

**----Code re-build steps for new custom FIX42.xml ---**

1. Copied quickfixj2.3.1.zip (url: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/releases )
2. Updated xml at path quickfixj-messages/quickfixj-messages-fix42/src/main/resources/FIX42.xml
3. run mvn build command.
4. Maven re-build jar for below:
   quickfixj-all
   quickfixj-core/
   quickfixj-messages/
   quickfixj-codegenerator/
   quickfixj-dictgenerator/
5. Tried using all above jar files in my RobotFramework with an assumption that it will now refer the modified QuoteRequest msg which has repeating group support.
   To my surprise, its output was exactly same. No changes.

After quickfixj rebuild for customised xml file.
**Final version of code snippet:**

```
public Message createMsg(String type, String message) 
{
        message = "35=" + type + "\001" + message;
        message = "8=FIX4.2\0019=" + message.length() + "\001"+message ;
        String msgCharStr = message.replaceAll("\\|", "\001");
        int checksum = MessageUtils.checksum(msgCharStr);
        msgCharStr = msgCharStr +"\00110=" +  (1 + 
        MessageUtils.checksum(msgCharStr)) + "\001" ;
        DataDictioanry dd = DataDictionary("FIX42.xml");
        quickfix.Message msg = new Message();
        msg.fromString(msgCharStr, dd ,true);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you are using to parse the messages.

Comment: @ChristophJohn: Edited details

Comment: When you are using a field order in repeating groups that is different from the one in the **default** dictionary then you need to follow one of these options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60048848/4962355

Comment: I tried that now but no luck. As I'm new to JAVA, just mentioning what I did to cater option1: 

- I copied my custom xml file at source code path ./src/main/resources/FIX42.xml. 
- Recompiled my code base with mvn (which internally re-build quickfixj from repository) 
- Later, I could see ./target/main/resources/FIX42.xml file with custom changes. This still shows me exactly same problem.

Comment: To which source code path exactly? It is not shown in the comment above. Maybe it is better to edit your question with the steps you did now.  Otherwise it can become very confusing.

Comment: @Chrisoph John: Edited my build steps.

Comment: It seems you do not pass in a data dictionary in your code. `msg.fromString` is using a `null` as parameter for the dictionary.

Comment: It seems you do not pass in a data dictionary in your code. `msg.fromString` is using a `null` as parameter for the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @Christoph it worked. 

With new modified xml changes for repeating group, rebuild the quickfixj code and above edited code(final version) I was able to parse FIX42 for partyId repeating group.