# How to build QuickFixJ from a custom dictionary?

Tags: java, maven, quickfixj

I have a highly customized version of FIX44.xml provided by a dealer. I need to generate QuickFixJ jar that uses this custom version. I am new to using Java and I am using IntelliJ IDE, JDK1.8 and Maven 3.8.6. I could not find clear instructions on how to build a jar using the Maven `quickfixj-codegenerator` plugin. Below is what I have in my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
 4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>CustomQuickFixJ</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.quickfixj</groupId>
            <artifactId>quickfixj-codegenerator</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>fixt11</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dictFile>FIXT11.xml</dictFile>
                        <packaging>com.custom.quickfix.fixt11</packaging>
                        <fieldPackage>com.custom.quickfix.field</fieldPackage>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>fix44-stp</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dictFile>FIX44-STP.xml</dictFile>
                        <packaging>com.custom.quickfix.fix44</packaging>
                        <fieldPackage>com.custom.quickfix.field</fieldPackage>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

I execute the Maven goal as follows on the cmd line

```
mvn -X org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator:generate
```

However, the build fails with following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator:2.3.1:generate (default- 
 cli) on project CustomQuickFixJ: QuickFIX code generator execution failed: 
 NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal 
 org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator:2.3.1:generate (default-cli) on project 
 CustomQuickFixJ: QuickFIX code generator execution failed
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
```

Also, I see the following in Maven output which makes me belive that my pom.xml configuration is not being used as the dictionary I really want to use is FIX44-STP.xml and it is not stored at the below "dictFile" path.

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator:2.3.1:generate' with basic 
configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) decimal = false
[DEBUG]   (s) dictFile = C:\IntelliJ- 
Projects\CustomQuickFixJ\src\main\quickfixj\dictionary\FIX44.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) fieldPackage = quickfix.field
[DEBUG]   (s) orderedFields = false
[DEBUG]   (s) outputDirectory = C:\IntelliJ-Projects\CustomQuickFixJ\target\generated-sources
[DEBUG]   (s) project = MavenProject: org.example:CustomQuickFixJ:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\IntelliJ- 
Projects\CustomQuickFixJ\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) schemaDirectory = C:\IntelliJ- 
Projects\CustomQuickFixJ\src\resources\quickfixj\codegenerator
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

After checking the quickfixj github repo at line 375 in MojoExecutor.java, I made a change to my maven cmd line as follows to provide "packaging" parameter but it didn't help

```
mvn -X -Dpackaging=com.custom.quickfix org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator:generate
```

Am I executing Maven goal incorrectly? Are there any clear instructions on how to use this plugin?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: The probably easiest way is to rename your dictionary to `FIX44.modified.xml`, put it into the `quickfixj-messages/quickfixj-messages-fix44/src/main/resources/` folder and rebuild the complete QFJ project. https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj#build-instructions (please note that you should probably omit the option `-PskipBundlePlugin` since there sometimes seems to be a NullPointerException when using it).

Comment: Thanks @ChristophJohn Should I leave FIX44.xml in the dir and overwrite the modified one with my dictionary? If there are two dictionary files in the same dir with the same protocol version, and one of them has custom fields, how does code generator decide which one to pick? For example, in my custom file, tag 150 ExecType has custom enum types which are not present in the base dictionary file. Thanks again.

Comment: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/0ef2ac42ac9966a965b9e811713b9b8c6bc7c32c/quickfixj-core/pom.xml#L249 There the file is specified.

Comment: Looking at your original question again: maybe you should try to pass the absolute path to your dictionary? Looks like it is not found?! But am no maven expert tbh.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your settings to be used you should execute `mvn clean install` from the same directory where your `pom.xml` is present

After `mvn clean install` finishes you should find the generated code in target/generated-sources/com/custom/quickfix/

Note that in the default `FIX44.xml`, fields `532=MassCancelRejectReason` and `139=MiscFeeType` will throw an error if you do not comment out the double-digit values which are incompatible with the CHAR type.

You can find a version that has those double digits commented out in the library `quickfixj-core:2.3.1/quickfixj-core-2.3.1.jar/FIX44.modified.xml`