# QuickFix: How to create a new custom group

Tags: quickfix

Would you please advise what is the way to create (Java) custom group. For instance, i need a group consists of three element (2101, 2102, 2103) so that fix message will be:

```
35=D|....|2100=1|2101=ETRSJSD|2102=ABCD|2103=5|
```

where 2100 include index of subgroup

QuickFix has similar ***NewSingleOrder.NoStrategyParameters()***

Comment: Here is an example how to create custom message and group: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60048848/4962355

Comment: @ChristophJohn thanks a lot for the example, i will give a try both options