# How to change order of tags in a FIX message using QuickFix/n

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

I am using QuickFix/n v1.10.0 Initiator and my client is requesting a custom field order for a message.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60048848/8483576) answer about QuickFix/j, I tried updating data dictionary but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: In QFJ at least changing the dictionary alone will not work, you also need to rebuild. Don't know about quickfixn.

Comment: I have a local environment set up so I am rebuilding the solution before each run if that is what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Ordering of top-level fields in the body doesn't matter.  QF (any of them) will order the fields in tag order.

Ordering of fields inside repeating groups DOES matter.  QF will expect fields within a group to match the order specified in the XML Data Dictionary.

For outgoing-message repeating groups, the ordering logic is in the compiled code (which is generated from the DD).  You will need to rebuild QF/n.  (Most QF initiator-only apps don't actually need this, as initiator-sent messages aren't usually customized very much by counterparties.)